# MVC inserting multiple items in database from checkbox

Tags: php, database, checkbox, sql-insert

View:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>some_controller/insert" method="post">

    <div id="choose app" style="width: 85%; height: 100px; overflow-y: scroll; padding:10px;">

            <?php foreach($people as $row){
            echo "<p><input type=radio name=name  value=".$row->id."/>".$row->app_name."</p>";}
            ?>
    </div>
</br>

2.) Choose Configuration Items

<a href ="">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>editButton.png" height=30 width=30 align=right hspace=5px>
</a>

<a href ="<?php echo base_url(); ?>some_controller/addCi_page">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>addButton.png" height=30 width=30 align=right hspace=5px>    
</a>

<hr>

<div id="choose app" style="width: 85%; height: 350px; overflow-y: scroll; padding:10px;">
        <?php 
            foreach($ciList as $row){
            echo "<p><input type=checkbox name=cname  value=".$row->affected_ci."/>".$row->affected_ci."</p>";
            }

        ?>
</div>
<hr>
<center><input type="submit" value="SAVE"/></center>

</br>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function insert_page(){
    $data['people'] = $this->some_model->getPeople();
    $data['ciList'] = $this->some_model->getCI();
    $this->load->view('templates/header.php', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/menu.php', $data); 
    $this->load->view('some_page/insert_page.php', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer.php');
}

public function insert(){
    $this->load->model('some_model');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $cname = $this->input->post('cname');

    $success = $this->some_model->insertPerson($name,$cname);

    if($success == TRUE)
        $this->insert_page(TRUE);
    else $this->insert_page(FALSE);
}
```

MODEL:

```
     public function insertPerson($name,$cname){
    $escName = $this->db->escape_str($name);
    $eciName = $this->db->escape_str($cname);
    $queryStr = "INSERT INTO appwarehouse.ci_table(app_id,ci_name) VALUES ('$escName','$eciName')";
    $query = $this->db->query($queryStr);
    return $query;
}
```

HELP! One value is from an option button and the other value is from check box. so same value for the first input but different for the other. How will i insert it in the one table from two different database.

Comment: what is the problem here, isn't the insert performed?

Comment: But only one value is inserted i need all the values checked in the check box to be inserted

Comment: then you need the checkbox as array `<input type=checkbox name=cname[]` and perform foreach/implode on it

Comment: you just call it many times

Comment: can you supply me with code :(

Comment: what is so difficult to understand?

Answer (score 2):

you can define your checkbox as array

```
<?php foreach($people as $row){
            echo "<p><input type=radio name=name[]  value=".$row->id."/>".$row->app_name."</p>";}
            ?>
<?php
 foreach($ciList as $row){
            echo "<p><input type=checkbox name=cname[]  value=".$row->affected_ci."/>".$row->affected_ci."</p>";
            }
```

?>

and on your controller

```
foreach($name as $key=>$value)
{
 $success = $this->some_model->insertPerson($value,$cname[$key]);
}
```

Comment: same value is inserted in the column for check box :(

Comment: what to change in the  model?